# KeyError: u'__module__'

Tags: python, django

Running Django 1.6, generates the error: KeyError: u'**module**'

Using Django 1.5.10, the error is: from django.db.models.loading import get_app_paths, get_apps
ImportError: cannot import name get_app_paths

How can I fix this?

```
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/models.py", line 14, in <module>
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 35, in <module>
class Page(six.with_metaclass(PageMetaClass, MP_Node)):
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 566, in with_metaclass
return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/metaclasses.py", line 17, in __new__
return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/o25/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 78, in __new__
module = attrs.pop('__module__')
  KeyError: u'__module__'
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version of `six` installed? Upgrade six by entering `pip install --upgrade six` on your terminal.

Comment: Yes, six was updated to the latest - same error. Any ideas how to debug?

Comment: What is your version of djangocms_text_ckeditor